# Given num = [3,4,2], target = 6, Because nums[1] + nums[2] = 6, return [1,2]

Tags: python, xcode

Whats wrong with this code?
the code is giving me the correct result but its not getting accepted in the submission of leet code?

```
def twoSum(self, nums, target):
nums=[2,7,11,15]
    target=9
    ret=[]
    for i in range (len(nums)):
        ret.append(i)
        if nums[i] + nums[i+1] == target :
            a=nums.index(nums[i+1])
            ret.append(a)
            return(ret)
            break
        elif nums[i] + nums[i+2] == target:
            a=nums.index(nums[i+2])
            ret.append(a)
            return(ret)
            break
        else:
            ret.pop(0)
```

Comment: Can you put here the submition rules?  We cannot see the error if don't know the  submition pattern.

Comment: Couple things. 1. You're calling `break` *after* a `return` statement, which is pointless. 2. `a=nums.index(nums[i+1])` will fail if you have duplicate values in the list. ie. `lst = [2, 6, 2, 1]`, just do `a = i+1` or `a = i+2`.

Answer (score 1):

The main point is using return is useless in code because you are not working with function.
 as you are calling nums[i] + nums[i+1] == target and nums[i] + nums[i+2] == target 
 In your question nums=[2,7,11,15] first two elements give the sum 9 so thats the reason it was working for you.
Think that if the nums=[11,15,2,1] then it will throw **list index out of range** because in the second condition nums[i] + nums[i+2] you are accessing the element which is beyond size.

replace for loop like this for i in range (len(nums)//2): and remove the return in both the coditions and at last line print(ret)